# aggregate function on sum and max on 2 table in sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 table 
`invm` and `invt`

`invm` has

```
i_b_no , i_b_dt , freight , tot_amt
1001 , 04/01/2015, 805 , 5000
1002 , 04/01/2015, 205 , 300
```

`invt` has

```
i_b_no , item_code, item_desc , stax_rate , amount
 1001 , xyz     , adlasjdlja,  12.5, 1000
 1001  , abc     , dfjsdffsdf,  12.5, 1000
 1001  , lkm     , sfkgsfksdn,  10.5, 1000
 1001  , rmn     , yeryoueoqe,  5.00, 1000
 1001  , the     , qwelskjfsdf,  12.5, 1000
1002   , dad     , sdfkdsffsdf , 10.0, 100
1002   , dekw    , kdasdahdafa , 3.2 , 100
1002    , dasdna , kdfnasldakdf, 6.8 , 100
```

now I want `sum ( (freight) * max(staxrate) /100 )`

which is `(805* 12.5)/100 = 1006.25`
         `(205 * 10)/100  = 20.5`

ans should be `1026.75`

I used

```
select sum (( sum (INVM.FREIGHT ) *  MAX (INVT.STAX_RATE) /100 ))
from invm inner join INVT on INVM.I_B_NO = INVT.I_B_NO 
where 
invm.i_b_dt between '04/01/2015 00:00:00' and '04/01/2015 00:00:00' 
group by INVM.FREIGHT
```

gives me error

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Cannot perform an aggregate
>   function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

.

i am stucked in this please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the `JOIN` in a derived table with the `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
select sum (FREIGHT * STAX_RATE / 100)
from (select INVM.FREIGHT as FREIGHT , MAX(INVT.STAX_RATE) as STAX_RATE
      from invm inner join INVT on INVM.I_B_NO = INVT.I_B_NO
      where invm.i_b_dt between '04/01/2015 00:00:00' and '04/01/2015 00:00:00'
      group by INVM.FREIGHT)
```

Comment: hey thanks buddy the secound querry worked for me sorry i can't give + point to u as i am new bee :(